C the end values of an array that was created in a seperate function have garbage values in them
This is the code that I used, all the printed values were 0 except the last 3 which were garbage values.
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARR_LEN 5

int* arrCreate();
void printArr(int* arr, int arrLen);

int main(void)
{
    int* arr = NULL;
    arr = arrCreate();
    printArr(arr, ARR_LEN);
    return 0;
}

int* arrCreate()
{
    int arr[ARR_LEN] = { 0 };
    return arr;
}

void printArr(int* arr, int arrLen)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arrLen; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", *(arr + i));
    }
}

What could cause that, and how to fix it? I specificly need to create an array in a seperate function, so just making the array in main wouldn't be what I need.

You cannot return arr; from arrCreate. That returns a pointer to an array, which does not exist anymore after the function ends.

Also, there is a rat in separate.
